# how to get all possible combinations from a dictionary using a range for each value

Tags: python, dictionary

How would I go about creating all possible combinations from this dictionary from a range given by the tuple in the dictionary?

```
def createCombo(self):
    usedAtoms = {'C':(0,100),'H':(0,200),'O':(0,4),'N':(0,4),'S':(0,4)}

    MolecularFormula.combinations(self, usedAtoms)

def combinations(self,dicts):

    product = [x for x in apply(itertools.product, dicts.values())]
    print [dict(zip(dicts.keys(), p)) for p in product]
```

Comment: You're almost there, just use the `range` function on each pair.

Comment: @AlexHall do you mean in the 'product =' part?

Comment: @IanDimitri yes, or in the definition of `usedAtoms`.

Comment: @AlexHall sorry for all the questions im new to python, but how would I integrate the range function into [x for x in apply(itertools.product, dicts.values())]??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` is deprecated in python now, use `*` to expand lists of arguments, e.g.

```
apply(itertools.product, dicts.values())
```

becomes

```
itertools.product(*dicts.values())
```

For your problem, replace `dicts.values()` with:

```
[range(*pair) for pair in dicts.values()]
```

Comment: AH! worked perfectly! thats better incase i have to make it dynamic! thank you so much